# Use IF condition in Foreach loop for comparision of data-bind values

Tags: javascript, if-statement, foreach, knockout-2.0

I need to compare a value which is returned from the db in a ForEach loop. I am not sure how to pik this value up (ie store it in a variable) and use it for comparison.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: ContractorList">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="#" data-bind="text: Contractor_Name, click: $root.listContractorDetails"></a>
                                    <span data-bind="text:Contractor_Status"></span>
                                    <span data-bind="if: some-syntax?? ">1</span>
                                    <span data-bind="if: same-syntaxt??">2</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

The data-bind="text:Contractor_Status" returns "Enrolled" or "Rejected", If Enrolled I want to show span 1 else span 2. Please can you help me with the syntax.

Comment: I tired adding a method (below) but it is always defaulting to the False position.

/*code*/
if (self.ContractorStatusList() == 'Enrolled')
                                IsAddPage: ko.observable(true);
                            else
                                IsAddPage: ko.observable(false);

Comment: I've tried to provide you an answer, but I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the IF condition in my HTML file instead of the .js file which solved the problem. 
Please not the following (to avoid the mistakes that I made) 
Closing tages for 
Double Equal to (as compared to ===) 
The get parameter ()

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: ContractorList">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <!-- ko if: (ContractorStatusList() == 'Enrolled')-->
                                    <span>1</span>
                                    <!--/ko -->
                                    <!-- ko if: (ContractorStatusList() == 'Rejected')-->
                                    <span>2</span>
                                    <!--/ko -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Each contractor in `ContractorList` should have the whole properties that you want later in your `if` bindings.

```
 // where 'x' is a property of each contractor:
 <span data-bind="if: x == 1">1</span>
 <span data-bind="if: x == 2">2</span>
```

These properties might be added using [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) in your *view model* source code like this:

```
var myViewModel = function() {
   // I'm sure you're populating this from a JSON source or who knows...
   this.ContractorList = ko.observableArray(); // or ko.observableArray([{}, {}, {}})...

   this.ContractorList.forEach(function(contractor) {
      // It's just a sample, you should set whatever you want in a property that you want
      // to use in an 'if' binding
      contractor.x = 1;
   });
};
```

Comment: Hi Matias, how would the compiler know what x is ? The ContractorList is an observable arroy with many values like Contractor_Name, Contractor_Status, etc. I want to pick up the Contractor_Status value (that I'm correctly getting) and use that for the IF comparison.Any suggestions ?

Comment: I tried this and it did not work

<td>
                                        <a href="#" data-bind="text: Contractor_Name, click: $root.listContractorDetails"></a>
                                        <span data-bind="text:Contractor_Status"></span>
                                        <span data-bind="if: {text:Contractor_Status=='Enrolled'}">1</span>
                                        <span data-bind="if: {text:Contractor_Status=='sdsds'}">2</span>
                                    </td>

Comment: @nyc_316 You need to study more about KO! It knows it because the context of a `foreach` binding is the object of current iteration, like an actual foreach in code.  If whatever doesn't work is because the property name has some type or who knows what... You should try to build a code snippet using the SO editor so I can run it and check what's wrong..

Comment: Matias, thanks for your help. 
Do you think the syntax of the code below is correct ?
<a href="#" data-bind="text: Contractor_Name, click: $root.listContractorDetails"></a>
                                        <span data-bind="text:Contractor_Status"></span>
                                        <span data-bind="if: {text:Contractor_Status=='Enrolled'}">1</span>
                                        <span data-bind="if: {text:Contractor_Status=='Rejected'}">2</span>

Comment: @nyc_316 It seems right... BTW, think SO isn't a chat... Here you need to provide a concrete issue and someone can assist you (like me), but it's not a black whole of nested questions :D